# Count relation and orderBy with Laravel 4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

This is my index action from my TagsController:

```
if(Input::get('filter') == 'most-used')
{
    $tags = Tag::with('questions')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->paginate(10);
    return View::make('tags.index', compact('tags'));
}
```

I would like the tags with the most questions first.

How do you do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do want to count number of questions?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it :

```
if(Input::get('filter') == 'most-used')
{
    $tags = Tag::select(
            '*',
            DB::raw("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `questions_tags` WHERE `tag_id` = `tags`.`id`) AS 'count'")
        )
        ->orderBy('count', 'desc')
        ->paginate(10);
    return View::make('tags.index', compact('tags'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:(*untested*)

```
$tags = Tag::with('questions')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->paginate(10);
$tags = $tags->sortBy(function($tag){
    return $tag->questions->count();
});
return View::make('tags.index', compact('tags'));
```

Comment: I doesn't work at all even if I change paginate() with get().

Comment: This will only sort the current page's tags, not ALL tags and then paginate those results.